# How can an IBM Worklight project be deployed on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, ibm-mobilefirst

How do I deploy an IBM worklight project on Windows Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Worklight works on Windows.More details available at the link below.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge IBM worklight only works on Linux. This means you'll need to exclude Windows Azure Web Sites and Windows Azure Cloud Services (Web Roles, Worker Roles, VM Roles).

The only way to run Linux in Windows Azure is by using [Windows Azure Virtual Machines](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/) (IaaS). The deployment of IBM worklight on Windows Azure Virtual Machines will be similar to a deployment on Amazon EC2. [Follow this guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_install_worklight_server_on_amazon_ec21?lang=en), but instead of creating the VM in Amazon EC2, create it in Windows Azure (by using the gallery for example).

Comment: Actually, IBM worklight does work on Windows. It's just that I do not know how to go about deploying IBM Worklight projects on Azure.